# How can I use HTTP with Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, http, post, sendgrid, fetch-api

I'm building an app with Angular (specifically Angular 5) and want to send emails with SendGrid using HTTP POST. I used Postman to verify that headers (including my API key) are correct. I had no issues doing this and received several test emails. I have not been able to get this set up within my code and don't know if I'm missing a certain module to make this work or if there is an issue within the function.

Here is the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
......
import { HttpModule, Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-invite',
  templateUrl: 'invite.html'
})
export class InvitePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public af: AngularFireDatabase, private http: Http) {
    ......
  }

  emailinvite(){
    var payload = {
      "personalizations": [
        {
          "to": [
            {
              "email": "myemail@gmail.com"
            }
          ],
          "subject": "Hello, World!"
        }
      ],
      "from": {
        "email": "from_address@example.com"
      },
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "text/plain",
          "value": "Hello, World!"
        }
      ]
    };
    var myHeaders = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer MY_API_KEY",
    });
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );
    fetch("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: data
    })
    .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
    .then(function(data){ console.log( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
  }
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help on this.

EDIT: I'm getting 3 errors when I fire the function: `Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` , `Fetch API cannot load https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send. Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` , and `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Type error`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this `fetch()` method for POST. I usually do `http.post()` like in this example: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-http-post-example

Comment: Any error message that you can share?

Comment: @DanielC. I'm getting 3 errors when I fire the function: `Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` , `Fetch API cannot load https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send. Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` , and `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Type error`.

Comment: Do you realize that by sending from the browser, you make your secret API key available to anyone using your application? And any such person can thus use your account to send mails? So, even if that worked, it would be a terrible idea.

Comment: @JBNizet This code is for an Android and iOS app that I'm working on, not a web application.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @cfoster5 Please take a look at the sengrid docs, Actually JB is right and also  sengrid documentation confirm that.  See the CORS section https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html   and how to integrate using a server technology https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/index.html  I think you should create a service from your app server and from that point call the sendgrid API.  Cheers